# DNS change from Godaddy to Netlify

Tags: dns, netlify

Problem:
I have svilab.com and [www.svilab.com](http://www.svilab.com) pointing to the managed DNS servers from Netlify.
I would like crm.svilab.com to point to a Godaddy IP address `160.153.33.96`

Here is what I have done so far:

Migrated my DNS from Godaddy to Netlify by changing the nameservers to

```
dns1.p06.nsone.net
dns2.p06.nsone.net
dns3.p06.nsone.net
dns4.p06.nsone.net
```

Created an `A record` that goes to crm.svilab.com -> 160.153.33.96 which is a godaddy server.

What I am expecting is to see:

A login page for the suitecrm I setup.

What I am actually seeing is:

`Future home of something quite cool.` I have verified that the home.html for this default page does not exist in the public_html on godaddy.

Comment: You did not "Create an A record that goes to crm.svilab.com -> 160.153.33.96", you can verify at https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=crm.svilab.com&type=A&showcommand=on&colorize=on&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=dns1.p06.nsone.net

Comment: @DusanBajic I do have an A record. Here's a screenshot on dropbox... https://www.dropbox.com/s/qc0o301h3dgl6it/svilabDNS.png?dl=0

Comment: Interesting. I can see that www.crm.svilab.com has the correct IP address, but crm.svilab.com does not. Can you maybe try deleting and creating it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I setup the A record correctly. See my dropbox [link](http://dropbox.com/s/qc0o301h3dgl6it/svilabDNS.png?dl=0)
The problem was on netlify's side. From their email...

> You made the record correctly. There is a known bug (cross-linked to this conversation for tracking) were sometimes, very rarely but sometimes, the DNS record gets created in our UI but not in the actual DNS server.
>
> So, our UI says there is a record, when in reality there isn't one.
>
> To clarify, you did everything correctly and it was a bug on our end. I deleted and recreated that A record in the Netlify UI and it worked the second time around.

Answer (score 0):

You can't point `crm.netlify.com` to choice of your server, as this is completely owned by netlify.

For pointing `crm.{yourdomain.example}` you need to create A record in your domains zone file pointing it to specific IP you want.

Comment: I have an a record the problem was on Netlify’s side. They fixed it.